# Can someone other than the original author contribute downstream changes to an upstream repo?

Tags: gpl, law, forking

Let's say we have repo A with a copyleft license like GPL. Let's say someone forks repo A to repo B and creates some modifications. Let's say the owner of B had no intention of contributing their changes to the upstream, but the original authors were interested in the modifications. Could the the authors of A (or some third party) legally "copy" the new code from the fork back to the upstream?

If yes, would attribution be required? (If we want to get into source control specifics, like Git, would it have to be the same commit?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, those changes could be added to any other repository - on the same conditions as the license asks.

It would not need to be the same commit or identically as the license is agnostic of the VCS used. But you would need to acknowledge the original author of that commit as usual. How to do that in practical terms might look different on circumstances. One might honour it in the commit message, could fudge the author data on commit, add it to the contributors list or as a note in the source itself at the appropriate place - or all of it.

Comment: Relying *only* on the commit messages to comply with the notice/attribution requirements would be a mistake, in my opinion. It's too easy for those to be excluded or missed by normal usage of source control tools. For example, if I use GitHub's "Download ZIP" feature, or SVN's "svn export" feature, then the resulting source tree should in principle still be a license-compliant copy. I.e. the attribution/notices really ought to be in the source tree somewhere as well.

Comment: @Brandin That is the problem of the use of the "Download ZIP" feature.  Unless you are saying someone including the attribution in the commit message, treating the repo as the work, is in violation.

Comment: Does "Download ZIP" not include the .git directory?

Comment: "Fudging the author data on commit" doesn't seem like a good idea as it would make it sound like _that author_ was doing the commit to the upstream.  Attributing the code to the author in the commit description is fine.

Comment: @davidbak I was not thinking of faking the author (that would be faking), but to add the textual author info like "pm@planetmaker.de <planetmaker based on work by davidbak>"

Comment: i see! I thought you were talking about changing the actual email.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater No, it doesn't. Just a snapshot of the source at that specific commit.

Comment: @davidbak With git, there is no distinction to which repository a commit "belongs" (was added first?). You can have the *same* commit in both repo A and B, possibly as part of a merge, you can have it rebased (with original author but new commiter), or you could make a new commit with copied (parts of the) code and still attribute the original author in the *author* field.

Comment: @Bergi - So the "metadata" in the commit - like committer - isn't part of the hash? Or the commit comment? IDNKT.

Comment: @davidbak The metadata is, as well as the graph of previous commits, but the repository isn't. You cannot distinguish whether the commit was made to the upstream repo, to the downstream fork repo, or to the repo on my local harddisk. It doesn't matter, its the same commit in any of them.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Whether it's a violation depends on interpretation and on the specific license. GPL, for example, says that it requires "prominent notices" that changes were made and when. If someone takes my GPL code and then publishes changes (as permitted by the license), but places the required notice that changes were made *only* in a Git commit message, and nowhere else in the source, then in my personal opinion, that does not fulfill the definition of a "prominent notice". I'm also not sure if the VCS commit messages should truly be considered part of the "Source Form" of the work.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - That's a bugger... Seems almost like an oversight

Answer (score 4):

Stepping back a bit, the fundamental point of open source is that *anyone* can take open source code and do *anything* with it.

Hopefully this makes the answer to your question obvious: it doesn't matter if the code was written by the upstream author, the downstream author, the upstream author's best friend, the downstream author's employee, the upstream author's worst enemy *or anyone else*: the upstream author (or the downstream author. Or anyone else) can take that code and use it however they wish.

Comment: Not *anything*. Very nearly all open source licenses place some restrictions. And the OP specifically asks about a copyleft license, which by definition will have more restrictions than most non-copyleft open-source licenses.

Answer (score 3):

Copyleft generally only applies when you redistribute the work or a derived work, but it doesn't *require* you to distribute it. If you made the copy just for personal use, repo B can be a private repo, and the authors of A (or a third party) would not be authorized to copy anything from it. The only redistribution requirement is that if you distribute object code you also have to distribute source code.

But if repo B is made public, I think its owner is implicitly authorizing anyone to copy from it, and this must be done in accordance to the requirements of the original copyleft license from A. This is the nature of copyleft -- it requires that whenever you pass on a copy of the original work or a derivative, you also pass on the same license (or a similar license, so long as it maintains these requirements).

So if the original license allows making derivatives without attribution, and you redistribute, you must also allow making derivatives without attribution.

Comment: Probably the second paragraph gets at the heart of the issue and is worth expanding. *Copyright* means the rights holder has sole authority to redistribute the work, which is implicitly what the OP question is about. But a copyleft license like GPL means that copyright doesn't apply as it otherwise might.

Comment: Well, copyleft is based on copyright. When you copyleft something, you're saying "By virtue of my copyright, I authorize you to copy the work as long as you follow these rules when you redistribute." And those rules include passing on the same rules.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by expanding on it, unless you mean explaining how copyleft works in detail.

Comment: I get the feeling that the original question has some misunderstandings about copyright and interactions with copyleft license, your first comment above I think would help clarify. ~ just a suggestion from someone who was previously similarly confused

Comment: I've added some more details.

Comment: > So repo B can be a private repo, and the authors of A (or a third party) would not be authorized to copy anything from it.

---

Out of curiosity, how can repo B be private if it's required to be distributed under GPL (using that license as an example)?

Comment: Read my first sentence: It's *not* required to be redistributed. You only have to distribute source if you distribute the object code. If you're just using it personally, you don't have to distribute anythning.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in terms of the **GNU GPL**:

B has made a *derivative work*.  The GPL requires that if B *distributes* this work to A (e.g. by publishing on a web site or public VCS repository), then that B must grant A all the freedoms of the GPL in respect of that derived work.

Therefore A is entitled to make and publish a work derived from B's code (in this case, by incorporating parts of it into A's original).

A can copy B's code in any way, and make whatever modifications desired.  There's no requirement to preserve the form (such as the sequence of commits) any more than B was required to preserve the exact form of A's code earlier.

As a *practical* matter, A will probably find it helpful to take B's commits as they are, before making changes on top of them, especially if anticipating further contributions from B.  But nothing in GNU GPL requires that.